# Change res/values/colors.xml on click button

Tags: xml, android-studio

I want to change the color #...... I put in my colors.xml file on button click but i don't now how to do it.
I want to propose to people many different choices of colors just like themes but defined by myself.

Using a code to change styles isn't working because I have many activities to change colors, all of them are using the same colors.xml file, I also have personalized and designed buttons

Don't know how to use sharedPreferences for this.

Got this in my colors xml file:

```
<color name="Primary">#C7EEFF</color>
<color name="UnderPrim">#98D4EE</color>
<color name="colorText">#142C36</color>
```

I want to change the value of "#C7EEFF" for example by clicking on a button

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a helper function that all places can call and set them.